# iOS: Reorder NSString characters alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way in Objective-C to reorder the character of a string alphabetically?

For example:

> Input: "fhwoijc"
>
> Output: "cfhijow"

This is what I came up with - it's a lot of work though

```
// Convert NSString to NSArray
NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *letters = @"fhwoijc";
[letters enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [letters length]) 
                            options:(NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences) 
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [letterArray addObject:substring];
}];

// Sort Array of strings alphabetically
[letterArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

// Convert Array back to NSString
NSString * result = [letterArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: Well done. This seems to handle all Unicode related problems that I could think of. I wouldn't expect anything built into the operating system; the really difficult part (splitting string into characters) is nicely handled by an operating system function.

Comment: Agree with @gnasher729, your solution is superior to any in the "duplicate".